# One method to capture most of the try catch statements

Tags: java, selenium, functional-interface

In my UI java test framework I have lots of methods that are doing try catch around element actions like click, send keys etc and return true when action is successful and false when any exception occurs. I was wondering is there any smarter way to pass the method as parameter and in that one method surround that code with try catch statement. So that code could be simpler and cleaner to read (may be Java 8 functional interfaces).

```
 public boolean expandPanel(String panelHeading) {
        boolean panelFound = false;
        try {
            getElement(PanelHeadings.fromString(panelHeading)).click();
            panelFound = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            panelFound = false;
        }
        return panelFound;
    }
```

I did try creating an actions class and defining different methods for click, sendKeys etc. But is there a way if i can just have one try catch method and pass code or behaviour to that method.

```
public boolean expandPanel(String panelHeading) {
       return actions.click(getElement(PanelHeadings.fromString(panelHeading)));
}

public class WebElementActions {
public Boolean click(WebElement element) {
        try {
            element.click();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like

```
public boolean executeSafely(Runnable action) {
    try {
        action.run();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception x) {
        return false;
   } 
}
```

And then call it with `return executeSafely(element::click)`.